# How to use appium to invoke adb command?

Tags: java, appium

How to use appium to invoke adb command.
This  `driver.executeScript ("mobile: shell", Cmd);` does not help, as this applies only to the internal Android system. I need to execute a command like
`adb backup -noshared com.android.chrome -f /home/profiles/chrome.adb`

But I need to do it without falls. If i do this directly from `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Cmd)`, appium will fall

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to look into [the ProcessBuilder class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "backup", "-noshared", "com.android.chrome", "-f", "/home/profiles.chrome.adb");
Process pc = pb.start();
pc.waitFor();
```

Comment: It provides a bit more control. I suppose I don't know what is failing for you. Can you share the failures you're receiving in your original question?